# UIScrollView with UIView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have implemented a UIScrollView with a UIView which I add when viewDidLoad() to the UIScrollView which is set to the UIViewControllers view. When I do this how ever the frame of the UIView with the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) gets set to -101.0. This does not happen to another view that is displayed differently,but only happens to this view which is designed the same, and displayed with pushViewController from the navigationController.

The constraints are setup from the NIB/XIB files and I am confused why this is occurring.

Another thing to note is that, when this happens, no matter where I try and change the frame of the UIView, it has no affect.

EDIT:
CODE for viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

        // call the super implementation
        super.viewDidLoad();

        // load our scrollview from our nib file
        customScrollView = CustomScrollView.loadFromNib();
        // set the resizeing mask to fill screen
        customScrollView!.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;

        // load our uiview from our nib file
        containerView = ContainerView.loadFromNib();
        // we handle the constraint changes
        containerView!.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false);
        customScrollView!.addSubview(containerView!);

        // intialize our refresh control
        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl();
        refreshControl!.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: "onRefresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged);
        containerView!.addSubview(refreshControl!);

        // add the view to our controller here
        view = customScrollView!;



    }
```

Comment: Could you share your viewDidLoad code. I would also check your .h file for any missing implementation in your second view controller class.

Comment: I will upload that code one second, but keep in mind, this is swift

Comment: I have updated the post with the view did load

Comment: you should probably include that it is Swift in the title or the first line as well, I see it is a tag already. Is this the code from the class that is not working or?

Comment: Yes this is code from the nonWorking Class, even though a similar implementation works when not using pushViewController

Comment: Also please note that, when switching the setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) to true/ not implementing that call. It does not cause a problem, but then I cannot update my constraints.

Comment: I am not seeing the issue in your code. Maybe Push effects it? Maybe consider embedding the UIScrollView in a View embedded in the view responding to the Push Segue. It works for Cocoa/Obj-C (I hope this makes sense).

Comment: unfortunately this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Hmmm I am drawing a blank then. Have you ever done the same process in Cocoa? It may be an issue with Swift as I know there are a variety of issues, which is normal with a new language and process. Sorry to say but I do not think I am able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being a custom tableview. If anyone else is having this problem, I highly recommend ditching UIScrollView, because it is an utter disappointment from apple. The documentation is poor, and there are technical issues with it known to be true. There are also technical document notes for some issues on the class for anyone who is trying to do something with the class, be sure to read those.